# JSONLD: How to convert a json into JsonLD?

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-spark, json-ld

I have a use case where I have a Json data and I have to convert that into JSONLD format.

**First Question** : Can this be done easily , like some API for this, that probably I am missing ?

**Second Question** : If not then what are the steps that needs to be taken.

So the Json Looks like :

```
{
key:"language",
value: "scala"
}
```

And I want to convert it into the JSONLD format.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219064/an-code-example-of-serialization-json-to-json-ld-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a context on this json object like :

```
{
  @context: {
        "key": "http://schema.org/description",
        "value": "http://schema.org/value"
      },
  key: "language",
  value: "scala"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in using JavaScript library to do this task, then npm module [JSONLD](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonld) is great one. 
**Note:** This library has dependency on PYTHON.

JavaScript code Example from JSONLD site:

```
var doc = {
  "http://schema.org/name": "Manu Sporny",
  "http://schema.org/url": {"@id": "http://manu.sporny.org/"},
  "http://schema.org/image": {"@id": "http://manu.sporny.org/images/manu.png"}
};
var context = {
  "name": "http://schema.org/name",
  "homepage": {"@id": "http://schema.org/url", "@type": "@id"},
  "image": {"@id": "http://schema.org/image", "@type": "@id"}
};

// compact a document according to a particular context
// see: http://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld/#compacted-document-form
jsonld.compact(doc, context, function(err, compacted) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(compacted, null, 2));
});
```

**Output:**

```
 {
    "@context": {...},
    "name": "Manu Sporny",
    "homepage": "http://manu.sporny.org/",
    "image": "http://manu.sporny.org/images/manu.png"
  }
```

When I was searching for JavaScript library for the JSON to JSONLD transformation, I could come up with this one. But, as this library has PYTHON dependency, I am searching for other JavaScript library for the same.